# Can I sleep in the landside section of Austin-Bergstrom airport?

Tags: airport-terminals, austin

Is the landside of Austin-Bergstrom ever closed at nights/early mornings?

Comment: A good first place to check is www.sleepinginairports.net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to SleepingInAirports](https://www.sleepinginairports.net/usa/austin.htm):

> - After security checkpoints close for the night, passengers are
>   restricted to landside only. Passengers who have arrived on a late
>   flight connecting to a morning flight are able to stay in the secure
>   area of the terminal.
> - A few reviews mention the loud and constant
>   overhead announcements that can be heard through most of the airport
>   (excluding the Mezzanine), so keep some earplugs or noise cancelling
>   headphones handy if you want to sleep!
> - For
>   uninterrupted sleep, there is a hotel on airport grounds and several
>   other nearby hotels that offer an airport shuttle. See Airport Hotels
>   below.